# will adding app engine to an existing project effect load balancers and existing static bucket?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have been running a static bucket with folders that act as routes to my sites url. I now need to add an app engine (suggestions for my case are appreciated) section to my site and run with a subdomain. (mysite.com/here)

Will i run into issues if i deploy app engine to the project?

How do I do this? App Engine will serve the subdomain (mysite.com/here) with a node.js project that has a package.json file and needs npm install.

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine does not support routes to Cloud Storage.

To implement this you must configure an HTTP(S) Load Balancer plus a Network Endpoint Group (NEG).

Google Cloud Storage only supports static files. You must preconfigure files that you wish to appear as static web pages.

[Network endpoint groups overview](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs)

[Set up a global external HTTP(S) load balancer (classic) with backend buckets](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-load-balancer-backend-buckets)

[Setting up a global external HTTP(S) load balancer (classic) with Cloud Run, App Engine, or Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless)

Comment: To implement this you must configure an HTTP(S) Load Balancer plus a Network Endpoint Group (NEG).  and then? where do i upload the files. sorry if this seems like a stupid question. like where would i get a file system I can run a node project.

Comment: @TeomanKirac - Post a new question and include details. The answer depends on many factors.

Comment: and in regards to: Google Cloud Storage only supports static files. You must preconfigure files that you wish to appear as static web pages.

does that mean I can add a route with a load balancer, and then since my new subdomain is not static, I run the proj in a container or something and can have the route be mysite.com/here ??

Comment: @TeomanKirac - Did you read the documentation links? The answer is probably yes, but that depends on details. I have no ideas how your application is designed. If your design is stateless, I would just use Cloud Run and store static files in Cloud Storage. However, please do not expand your original question in the comments, Post a new question. Your goal is to provide one well-defined question per post.

Comment: Thanks John will expand in a new question.